# Can't scroll with d3.js draw tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm doing a javascript for drawing tree, but the tree part is being hidden. I need scroll for large data. Can I add more attribute in somewhere in the code below

[image]

```js
// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
            var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 350 },
                width = screen.height - margin.right - margin.left,
                height = screen.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var i = 0;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);

            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .style('overflow', 'auto')
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var root = treeData[0];
```

Comment: I follow this code for drawing:

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092